# AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, tensorflow

#@title Using Tensorflow object detection API to find Waldo

```
    def display_image(image):
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.imshow(image)

    def download_and_resize_image(url, new_width=256, new_height=256,
                              display=False):
  _, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=".jpg")
  response = urlopen(url)
  image_data = response.read()
  image_data = BytesIO(image_data)
  pil_image = Image.open(image_data)
  pil_image = ImageOps.fit(pil_image, (new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
  pil_image_rgb = pil_image.convert("RGB")
  pil_image_rgb.save(filename, format="JPEG", quality=90)
  print("Image downloaded to %s." % filename)
  if display:
    display_image(pil_image)
  return filename

def draw_bounding_box_on_image(image,
                               ymin,
                               xmin,
                               ymax,
                               xmax,
                               color,
                               font,
                               thickness=4,
                               display_str_list=()):
  """Adds a bounding box to an image."""
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
  im_width, im_height = image.size
  (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                                ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
  draw.line([(left, top), (left, bottom), (right, bottom), (right, top),
             (left, top)],
            width=thickness,
            fill=color)
```

If the total height of the display strings added to the top of the bounding
box exceeds the top of the image, stack the strings below the bounding box
instead of above.

```
display_str_heights = [font.getsize(ds)[1] for ds in display_str_list]
```

Each display_str has a top and bottom margin of 0.05x.

```
total_display_str_height = (1 + 2 * 0.05) * sum(display_str_heights)

if top > total_display_str_height:
    text_bottom = top
  else:
    text_bottom = top + total_display_str_height
```

Reverse list and print from bottom to top.

```
for display_str in display_str_list[::-1]:
    text_width, text_height = font.getsize(display_str)
    margin = np.ceil(0.05 * text_height)
    draw.rectangle([(left, text_bottom - text_height - 2 * margin),
                    (left + text_width, text_bottom)],
                   fill=color)
    draw.text((left + margin, text_bottom - text_height - margin),
              display_str,
              fill="black",
              font=font)
    text_bottom -= text_height - 2 * margin
```

Overlay labeled boxes on an image with formatted scores and label names.

```
    def draw_boxes(image, boxes, class_names, scores, max_boxes=10, min_score=0.1):
    colors = list(ImageColor.colormap.values())
    
      try:
        font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSansNarrow-Regular.ttf",
                                  25)
      except IOError:
        print("Font not found, using default font.")
        font = ImageFont.load_default()
    
      for i in range(min(boxes.shape[0], max_boxes)):
        if scores[i] >= min_score:
          ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tuple(boxes[i])
          display_str = "{}: {}%".format(class_names[i].decode("ascii"),
                                         int(100 * scores[i]))
          color = colors[hash(class_names[i]) % len(colors)]
          image_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert("RGB")
          draw_bounding_box_on_image(
              image_pil,
              ymin,
              xmin,
              ymax,
              xmax,
              color,
              font,
              display_str_list=[display_str])
          np.copyto(image, np.array(image_pil))
      return image

def load_img(path):
  img = tf.io.read_file(path)
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  return img

def run_detector(detector, path):
  img = load_img(path)

  converted_img  = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)[tf.newaxis, ...]
  start_time = time.time()
  result = detector(converted_img)
  end_time = time.time()

  result = {key:value.numpy() for key,value in result.items()}

  print("Found %d objects." % len(result["detection_scores"]))
  print("Inference time: ", end_time-start_time)

  image_with_boxes = draw_boxes(
      img.numpy(), result["detection_boxes"],
      result["detection_class_entities"], result["detection_scores"])

  display_image(image_with_boxes)

def detect_img(image_url):
  start_time = time.time()
  image_path = download_and_resize_image(image_url, 64, 64)
  run_detector(detector, image_path)
  end_time = time.time()
  print("Inference time:",end_time-start_time)

detector = model
```

https://ibb.co/GQ0ms8S

```
detect_img('https://i.ibb.co/23yJ8C4/waldo-6.jpg')
```

The error line -> result = {key:value.numpy() for key,value in result.items()}

Comment: How did you create `detector`/`model`?  You didn't show that.  The code you copied from their sample loads a module from a hub.

Comment: Can you please  checkout the answers from link.https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29972#issuecomment-504591877